# How to fix TS error 'type is missing' when working with jest and History?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm writing tests and I'm using a mock `history` object, however TS keeps throwing the below error:

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Location<IHistoryMock>': pathname, search, state, hash
```

I'm not sure how to get around this. I've tried extending the History interface and rewriting it every way that I could think of. Here's what I have so far:

```
import { History, Location } from 'history';

interface IHistoryMock extends History {
  location: Location | any;
}

const historyMock: History<IHistoryMock> = { push: jest.fn(), createHref: () => '', location: { }, listen: jest.fn() };

mount(
  <Router history={historyMock}>
    <Component id="id" />
  </Router>
);
```

Typescript underlines `location: { }` and throws the above error. Am I incorrectly extending `History`? I need a `location` to be an empty object here, and I don't want to use the `any` type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `createLocation` function in `history` library for creating Location mock

```
import { createLocation } from 'history';
...
const historyMock: History<IHistoryMock> = { push: jest.fn(), createHref: () => '', location: createLocation('/'), listen: jest.fn() };
```

Comment: It's still throwing a similar error, `Type '{ push: Mock<any, any>; createHref: () => string; location: Location<IHistoryMock>; listen: Mock<any, any>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'History<IHistoryMock>': length, action, replace, go, and 3 more`

Comment: try to use `createBrowserHistory` function in `history` to create History mock. It should be a better solution instead of creating History mock yourself.